# Вывод значения из большого словаря. Выборка из API Tinkoff. Язык Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

Входные данные https://api.tinkoff.ru/v1/currency_rates

Если я правильно понимаю, по ссылке выдается массив с разными словарями, которые имеют одинаковые пары ключей.
Нужно вытянуть значение пары Sell:"текущий курс покупки доллара" в словаре со значением 'category': 'DebitCardsOperations'.

Код выглядит так

```
import requests
import json


def get_usd():
    url = "https://api.tinkoff.ru/v1/currency_rates"
    r = requests.get(url).json()
    rate_dict = (r["payload"]["rates"]) #получаем массив rates, который содержит всё что нам надо
    def has_sale(string): #здесь я пытался вытянуть значение sell, но вытянул все словари, которые содержат значение sell
        return "sell" in string

    l = list(filter(has_sale, rate_dict))

    print(l)
```

Дальше я запутался

Answer (score 0):

У вас `rate_dict` - это список, содержащий словари. Вы можете обойти в цикле этот список и вывести только те словари, у которых значение ключа `category` это `DebitCardsOperations`.

```
import requests
import json


def get_usd():
    url = "https://api.tinkoff.ru/v1/currency_rates"
    r = requests.get(url).json()
    rate_dict = (r["payload"]["rates"]) #получаем массив rates, который содержит всё что нам надо

    for rate in rate_dict:
        if rate["category"] == "DebitCardsOperations":
            print(rate)
            print("sell: ", rate["sell"])


get_usd()
```

Пример вывода значения `sell` каждого словаря из списка:

```
sell_list = [
    {'sell': 1},
    {'sell': 2},
    {'sell': 3},
    {'sell': 4},
]


for s in sell_list:
    print(s)
    print(s['sell'])

# Результат:
# {'sell': 1}
# 1
# {'sell': 2}
# 2
# {'sell': 3}
# 3
# {'sell': 4}
# 4
```

Пример вывода значений из словаря:

```
rate = {
    'category': 'DebitCardsOperations', 
    'fromCurrency': {'code': 840, 'name': 'USD', 'strCode': '840'}, 
    'toCurrency': {'code': 643, 'name': 'RUB', 'strCode': '643'}, 
    'buy': 64.6, 
    'sell': 67.25
}


print(rate['category'])
# DebitCardsOperations

print(rate['fromCurrency'])
# {'code': 840, 'name': 'USD', 'strCode': '840'}

print(rate['fromCurrency']['name'])
# USD

print(rate['sell'])
# 67.25
```

Comment: Спасибо, функция сработала частично. Вывела все словари с этим значением. К сожалению, я не до конца понял, как вы к этому пришли, поэтому я не могу продолжить код по выборке.

Теперь я получаю словарь с разными парами валют rub/usd, usd/euro и т.п.

Возможно, я где-то пропустил базовые знания (

Comment: У вас сложности с получением значений из словаря по ключу?

Comment: Судя по всему, да. Я также получаю множество словарей. Если я закрываю print(rate) т.е. удаляю строку или делаю её комментарием - я получаю множество значений sell, которые имеют разные значения. Как я понимаю, это зависит от пары валюта\валюта в словарях.

Comment: У каждого словаря в списке есть значение `sell`. Мы просто выводим их. Я добавил к ответу пару примеров. Надеюсь, станет понятнее. Если нет, то почитайте что-нибудь о том, как работать со словарями и списками в Python.

Comment: Суть в том, что словарь меняется когда меняется курс.

rate = {
    'category': 'DebitCardsOperations', 
    'fromCurrency': {'code': 840, 'name': 'USD', 'strCode': '840'}, 
    'toCurrency': {'code': 643, 'name': 'RUB', 'strCode': '643'}, 
    'buy': 64.6, 
    'sell': 67.25
}

Если брать значение из этой конструкции, она потеряется при следующем изменении словаря. Разве не так?

Comment: Да, значение может измениться, когда вы запросите  в следующий раз. Сама структура словаря останется той же. То есть вам нужно будет выполнить тот же код снова для получения обновленных значений.

Answer (score 0):

Получил нужные данные, требовалось добавить еще несколько условий. Спасибо за помощь. Теперь код выглядит так:

```
def get_usd():
    url = 'https://api.tinkoff.ru/v1/currency_rates'
    r = requests.get(url).json()
    rate_dict = (r['payload']['rates'])
    for rate in rate_dict:
        if rate['category'] == 'DebitCardsOperations' and rate['fromCurrency']['name'] == 'USD' and rate['toCurrency']['name'] == 'RUB':

            # print(rate['category'])
            # print(rate['fromCurrency'])
            # print(rate['toCurrency'])
            # print(rate['fromCurrency']['name'])
            # print(rate['toCurrency']['name'])
            print(rate['sell'])

get_usd()
```